# Unable to delete Cloud Function because of EventArc trigger permission error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm trying to delete a cloud function (gen2) that was triggered off of a google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized eventarc message. The error I'm getting is the following.

```
gcloud functions delete my-function --region europe-west4 --gen2
2nd gen function \[projects/my-project/locations/europe-west4/functions/my-function\] will be deleted.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Preparing function...done.  
X Deleting function...  
. \[Artifact Registry\]  
. \[Service\]

- \[Trigger\] Deleting Eventarc trigger...  
  Failed.  
  ERROR: (gcloud.functions.delete) OperationError: code=7, message=Deleting trigger failed for projects/my-project/locations/europe-west4/triggers/my-function: generic::permission_denied: Caller does not have required permission to use project my-project. Grant the caller the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role with the serviceusage.services.use permission, by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=my-project and then retry. Propagation of the new permission may take a few minutes.
```

If I try to delete the trigger directly, I get the same error.

> Deleting trigger [my-trigger] in project [my-project], location [europe-west4]...failed.                 ERROR: (gcloud.eventarc.triggers.delete) generic::permission_denied: Caller does not have required permission to use project my-project. Grant the caller the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role with the serviceusage.services.use permission, by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=my-project and then retry. Propagation of the new permission may take a few minutes.

I'm running these commands with a Org Owner will all rights, and I've even tried explicitly adding that "roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer" role, but I still can't delete the function.

Comment: Since I didn't have any other cloud functions in the project, I was able to solve the problem by disabling the Eventarc and Cloud Function APIs. However, this wouldn't have worked if I had had other Cloud Functions. I'm hoping someone at google can solve the underlying issue in Eventarc.